# Text processing pipeline for updating many source code files

Tags: build, automation, build-automation, pipeline

I need to take unspecified set of source code files and do the following operations:

- If I find a declaration of certain type (basically, if I find a keyword in line based on a Regexp or simple search pattern) I need to add certain pre-defined fixed lines before that line.
- I need to add standard comment above everything in the file
- I need to perform cleanup of some lines or set of lines based on some criteria, for simplicity, based on Regexp search.

I have to run this on Windows machine, as source code will be .NET and Java, and as such I need tools that can be installed on Windows, but I am OK for instance with Cygwin etc.

Answer (score 0):

there are three questions, not just one - hope that you are not going to set up a minus for a one suggestion only :) 
If you know Linux shell, and I guess Cywin is the same shell basics, then the second question. 
To add a standard comment on the top of each file, just 
cat StdCommentFile SourceFile.h >> tempDir/SourceFile.h 
In other words, you need to add a tempDir for the output. Of course if the standard heading is very simple, a small sed command could be OK. 
The cleaning based on the regular expressions might need to be done with sed command too. I am a bit high level, since the details are not there :) Does that cleanup mean removal of entire lines or just a few phrases.